# Storing variable name option in MySQL

Tags: mysql, optimization

Let's say you have a database with a bunch of users, and you need to store a random quantity of random key-value pairs. Each user can have a variable (very variable) set of pairs and keys are can be completely unrelated one from another, but also can be repeated. Also, the key-value pairs are written quite often, but most of the time a user read, reads all of theirs key-value pairs at once. The key-value pairs can be to the order of the thousands per each user, but as said, it can really be variable (can be 1, like can be 1000)

So far I've come to three possible solutions:

1. A column in the user table where a JSON (or another suitable serialization) is stored, representing the key-value pairs set for that user. Probably the best read-wise, but I'm concerned about the insertion
2. A "keyvalue" table that has as columns the user id, the key as VARCHAR and the value.
3. Two tables, one called "keyname" with the key_id as INT and the key_name as VARCHAR, and the keyvalue table from the point 2, but with key_id instead of the key.

Which one is the best performance-wise in MySQL (or if there is any other option better than those)? Which optimization could be applied to the database to make it work better? (Views, indexes, etc. Etc.)

Comment: EAV looks like suitable pattern. *I'm concerned about the insertion* JSON_MERGE() or JSON_MERGE_PATCH().

Comment: You pretty much listed out the options you have (the one you are missing is using a nosql solution, which is more suitable for such requirements). The problem is: we can't tell you which one works the best for your specific requirements and infrastructure! You need to test the solutions and choose the one the fits your requirements the best. You wrote you were concerned about the insertion of json data. Testing it would either confirm or refute your concern, rather than relying on the words of people, who cannot possibly know anything about your system.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE kvs (
    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    key VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    val ? NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, key),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Notes:

- Because InnoDB "clusters" the PK with the data, all the k-v pairs for a given user are "consecutive", thereby efficient to fetch.
- There is no need to have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` PK; you have a suitable 'natural' PK.
- The "value" may be either `VARCHAR(255)`, or, if you need bigger values, `TEXT`.  (There are other options, but these seem likely.)
- `key` must not be `TEXT` because of the indexing.  If you need big keys, this schema won't work as it stands.  Please specify the requirements for `key`.
- This schema is probably optimal for the two queries you described; if there will be more queries, I may need to adjust.  Note, in particular, it is quite clumsy to put numbers in `TEXT` and expect them to be compared numerically.
- *That schema assumes the conventional meaning of "key-value", namely that a user has only one row per key.*  So...

Assuming that a user can have duplicate keys, and, furthermore, that a key-value pair can be duplicated for a user:

```
CREATE TABLE kvs (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    key VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    val ? NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, id),  -- clustered on user_id, made unique via `id`
    INDEX(id)   -- to keep auto_increment happy
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Uhm, the only problem is that the key may be duplicated for each user, as I wrote

Comment: @Francexi - If `val` is not too big, then use `PRIMARY KEY(user_id, key, val)`

Comment: also the val may be duplicated. Basically, the pairs should not be assumed to be unique in any way

Comment: @Francexi - OK, I added another suggestion, based on the possibility of _duplicate rows_.   If I still don't understand the question, please provide some samples of rows that show the various possible dups _and_ samples of rows (if any) that should not be allowed.